# Transform Process ID (`pid`) in Elixir to Tuple or string; Parse `pid` to other types

Tags: elixir

How do I transform a Process ID `PID` into a tuple or string?

For example, let's say I have a PID named `my_pid`

```
iex(1)> my_pid
#PID<0.1692.0>
```

How would I transform the PID ID to a tuple or a string to get either?

```
{ 0, 1692, 0 }
```

or

```
"0.1692.0"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are after `:erlang.pid_to_list/1` and `:erlang.list_to_pid/1` functions.

```elixir
list = self() |> :erlang.pid_to_list()
#⇒ [60, 48, 46, 49, 49, 48, 46, 48, 62]
to_string(list)
#⇒ "<0.110.0>"
list |> List.delete_at(0) |> List.delete_at(-1) |> to_string()
#⇒ "0.110.0"
```

The advantage of this approach is that it’s convertible

```elixir
:erlang.list_to_pid(list)
#⇒ #PID<0.110.0>
```

Comment: Aleksei - thanks (as ever) for bringing concision and elegance - yes my answer is way too hacky!

Answer (score 6):

step by step:

```
pid = self()         # gets shells pid e.g. #PID<0.105.0>

a = "#{inspect pid}" # gives the string "#PID<0.105.0>"

b = String.slice a, 5,100 # remove the prefix #PID<
c = String.trim b, ">"    # remove the postfix >
d = String.split c, "."   # create list of strings: ["0", "105", "0"]

e = Enum.map( d ,fn x -> String.to_integer(x) end) # converts to a list of integers
f = Enum.join(e, " ")
```

result: `"0 105 0"`

Comment: Thanks! I feel like this should almost be part of the standard library, but creating a function for this won't be hard either.

Comment: this shouldn't and won't be part of standard library. pid's are treated as separate structure with limited functionality for a reason and it is strongly discouraged their manipulation.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff This is too hacky, please see my answer.

Comment: @Daniel sure it’s a part of standard library, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful approach to getting `pid` from a string representation of pid(eg. `#PID<0.127.0>`) is below, it's a derived version of [Aleksei's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70105854/15843766).

Below is the snippet from iex session:

```bash
iex(1)> pid = "#PID<0.127.0>" |> String.trim_leading("#PID") |> String.to_charlist |> :erlang.list_to_pid  
#PID<0.127.0>
iex(2)> Process.alive?(pid)
true
```